# Erase a character when stty is set to raw mode in C

Tags: terminal, tty

I was trying to get a paragraph of text including the newlines without the user needing to press enter everytime the getch untill the user presses CTRL+C at which point loop shown below will exit out . But the problem using this approach in that , once the terminal is set into raw mode , it also shows those `^M` when i press Enter and shows the `^?` when I press `backspace`. How to fix this ? I have also tried giving `system("/bin/stty raw -echo isig");`But this method also didnt work( no charecters show as i type)

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[1000] ,c , i=0 ;

    system("/bin/stty raw") ;
    while(1)
    {
        c = getchar();
        str[i++] = c ;
        if(c==3)break;
        if(c==13)puts("\r");
    }

    system("/bin/stty cooked") ;

    for(i=0 ;str[i] ; i++) printf("%c",str[i]) ;
}
```

Also the string produced at the end (str) is also not having the right characters. In fact when i print it , it only prints the last line.

Comment: Why not `putc(str[i])` instead of `printf("%c",str[i])`?

Comment: You can't have the cake and eat it. If you want raw, you get it. Question is why raw mode if you don't want it.

Comment: becoz i don't want it to wait untill the user presses enter after entering each character for it to be processed . In raw mode , it would accept the character as soon as i press any character and doesn't wait till enter is pressed .

Answer (score 0):

You can try `printf("\b \b");` to erase a character, but first you have to check whether or not the `backspace` was pressed, you will need to find out the code for `backspace` in your particular machine :

```
if (ch == 0x7F)         // the code for backspace on my machine
    printf("\b \b");    // simulate erasing a character using two '\b' and a space ' '
```

alternatively you can use [VT100 escape codes](http://www.climagic.org/mirrors/VT100_Escape_Codes.html):

```
if (ch == 0x7F)         // the code for backspace on my machine
    printf("\b\33[K");  // clear line from cursor right
```